# How to test app on Edge on Mac OS or Linux

Tags: microsoft-edge

I am on Mac OS and Linux and want to test my app on Edge.  I know I can use Browserstack, but it's a paid service.  Any other ways that I can test on Edge for Free?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you are on Mac or Linux, you can use the following tools to test Edge for **free**:

**Virtual Machines** 
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/
You can get the virtual machines image to test Edge as well as IE6 to IE11 on all platforms Mac, Linux and Windows. You do need to have either Virtual Box, VMware or Vagrant to install the VM image.

**RemoteIE**
https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/remote/ 
If you don't want to install VM image, try RemoteIE. The Remote client app is a small utility program that allows you to access Microsoft apps from the cloud. When you launch Internet Explorer from the Remote client app, a real preview version of the browser opens into a new window on your operating system, much like any other app you might have running. This version of Internet Explorer is modified to host the latest preview version of the EdgeHTML rendering engine, so you can test how your site will render in Microsoft Edge. It is available for Mac OS X, iOS, Android and Windows OS devices, and includes simple installation and account set up steps.

Comment: RemoteIE is no longer available

Comment: Remote IE is not available for testing for MS Edge browser.

Comment: You can try this: https://www.browserstack.com/test-on-microsoft-edge-browser#live-cloud

Comment: Browserstack trial now gives you 30 minutes of free testing on famous browsers (including Edge) that can be tested on any device and operating system virtually!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, using virtual machines. Microsoft provides VMs in a number of formats for exactly this reason.

[You can download them here](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/mac)

Answer (score 0):

You can download MS Edge with support for Apple Silicon at https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge/download/insider